# Rails 3 - how can I customize text-label in label helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, label, helper

This is probably a bit low question, but is there any elegant way, how to change the label-text in **label** helper?

```
= f.label :name
```

generate

```
<input id="car_name" name="car[name]" size="30" type="text">
```

If I would like to have the text in **label**, say, **Your Car** instead of **Name**, how to do that?

One way is to write the label tag directly as HTML, but this is a bit dirty way...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add a second string argument to f.label, like this:

```
label_tag 'name', 'Your name'
# => <label for="name">Your Name</label>
```

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag)