# How to Titleize a Rails Label_Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, label

How do you get a Rails label to use the titelize format so that instead of getting "To date" I would get "To Date"

```
label_tag 'To Date'
```

displays 'To date'since Rails defaults to human readable formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom text for rails form\_for label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003626/custom-text-for-rails-form-for-label)

Comment: Or you could use a custom form builder, which isn't covered in the referenced link.

Comment: I updated the title to specify that this was for a label_tag which isn't covered by the question you mentioned

Comment: @BradWerth, I added one solution, not sure why down voted, instead of knocking for not showing a custom form builder, you can add as another answer

Comment: OK, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473565/rails-3-how-can-i-customize-text-label-in-label-helper then... This is a dupe of dozens of existing questions, and your answer is the least idiomatic way to do it, which is probably why you were downvoted. I am not inclined to answer trivial dupes.

Answer (score -1):

```
label_tag('to_date', 'To Date', class: 'control-label')
```

displays 'To Date' with html of:

```
<label for="to_date">To Date:</label>
```

[Per the documentation:][1]

label_tag(name = nil, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)